# Running different function parallel in python3.7 using multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I want to run two different function in parallel in python, I have used the below code :

```
def remove_special_char(data):
    data['Description'] = data['Description'].apply(lambda val: re.sub(r'^=', "'=", str(val))) # Change cell values which start with '=' sign leading to Excel formula issues
    return(data)

file_path1 = '.\file1.xlsx'
file_path2 = '.\file2.xlsx'


def method1(file_path1):
    data = pd.read_excel(file_path1)
    data= remove_special_char(data)
    return data

def method2(file_path2):
    data = pd.read_excel(file_path2)
    data= remove_special_char(data)
    return data
```

I am using the below `Pool` process , but its not working.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

p = Pool(3)
result1 = p.map(method1(file_path1), args=file_path1) 
result2 = p.map(method2(file_path1), args=file_path2)
```

I want to run both these methods in parallel to save execution time and at the same time get the return value as well.

Comment: The idea of multiprocessing is doing something like: `result = p.map(method, (file_path1, file_path2))`. Why are you defining the same function twice?

Comment: @Tomerikoo- how will `result` will store data from two different file location.I need separate `return` from both the function.

Comment: It returns a list...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are defining the same method twice with different parameter names, but anyway the [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) method of [`Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool)s is taking as its first argument a function, and the second argument is an iterable. What `map` does is call the function on each item of the iterable, and return a list with all the results. So what you want to do is more something like:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

file_paths = ('.\file1.xlsx', '.\file2.xlsx')

def method(file_path):
    data = pd.read_excel(file_path)
    data= remove_special_char(data)
    return data

with Pool(3) as p:
    result = p.map(method, file_paths)
```

Comment: My mistake, actually both methods are different and in actual scenario I am performing more task under both the methods. However I tried the your way as well, but not sure why its running in the background and not giving any output.